# Detect specific touch location within a sprite cocos2d

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

[image]

In the image above, the yellow represents a sprite that is bigger than the iPad resolution. I would like to allow drag drop functionality on a specific location which is represented here in white.

What I have is :
 - CCActor inherits CCSprite
 - targetedBoundingBox is the boundingBox of the white circle according to the sprite.

What I want:
How I can get the touchLocation according to the sprite not to the screen?

My code:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    CCActor * newSprite = [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];
    if(newSprite != NULL){
        //touchLocation should be according to the sprite.
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(newSprite.targetedBoundingBox, touchLocation)) {
            [self spriteSelected:newSprite];
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head the easiest way to do this is to calculate the difference between your touch location and the sprite's location, so your code should look as follows:

first define this somewhere global in your class

```
CCPoint relativePosition;
```

And then from inside the touch code just calculate the difference between your touch location and the sprite's position (only done if the touch is actually inside the sprite, meaning you won't get x=-100, y=-999 if you touch outside the sprite)

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    CCPoint actorPosition = [actor position];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(actor.targetedBoundingBox, touchLocation)) {
      //You now have the touch position here:
      relativePosition = ccpSub(touchLocation, actorPosition);
      return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

the code is not tested, just wrote it off the top of my head, I'm sure there's mistakes but it's a hint on which direction you should go !, also depending on what you're doing, there are better ways to handle this, take [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d) as an example

If i'm not making sense please correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, "what I want:How I can get the touchLocation according to the sprite not to the screen?", first you should understand that currently Cocos2D handles all touches in a centralised manner at the level of the layer, rather than at the level of the sprite.

Hence touches received in the UIView coordinates have to be converted to the layer(node space) coordinates and then check whether the touch intersects the concerned sprite. For a reference implementation, you may check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d).

If I understood your question correctly, you want to go one step further and identify the exact coordinates in the concerned sprite, then it is a basic
  directionDistance = (newSprite.x,newSprite.y) -(touchlocation.x,touchlocation.y)  within touch intersects sprite condition, to get the direction and/or distance from the center of the sprite,to get to the exact touch location within the concerned sprite.